# Measure execution coverage in Jupyter kernel

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, coverage.py

I tried to measure coverage with the following kernel specification, but it did not write any results. I wonder why this is the case. The parallel flag does not create any coverage result file either.

Note that the path to the python is actually an absolute path, which I've shortened for demonstration purposes only.
Content of ~/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/py3_cov/coverage_kernel.json

```
{
 "argv": [
  "python",
  "-m",
  "coverage", "run", 
  "--concurrency=thread",
  "-p",
  "-m",
  "ipykernel_launcher",
  "-f",
  "{connection_file}"
 ],
 "display_name": "py3_cov",
 "language": "python"
}
```

It is expected, that every code which runs within the kernel gets written to the coverage results file. Please advice me, if this thought is wrong or I've simply done something wrong.

I know there are several tools already which wrap around notebook execution and coverage (like nbval, pytest-notebook etc.). I explicitly ask this, since I do not want to stick to another toolchain for this (simple?!) purpose.

Comment: Is it possible the kernel is spawning subprocesses? https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/coverage-5.5/subprocess.html

Comment: Thanks for the hint, just tested "--concurrency=multiprocessing" as well with no luck

Answer (score 0):

Using --concurrency=multiprocessing does the trick. But you need to pass an rcfile setting the options for the subprocesses.

```
{
 "argv": [
  "python",
  "-m",
  "coverage", "run", 
  "--concurrency=multiprocessing",
  "--rcfile=../setup.cfg"
  "-p",
  "-m",
  "ipykernel_launcher",
  "-f",
  "{connection_file}"
 ],
 "display_name": "py3_cov",
 "language": "python"
}
```

Now when executing the notebook via jupyter nbconvert --execute, I get a coverage file lying next to the input notebook file :)

Comment: used jupyter kernelspec install $dir_containing_json_file --name $same_name_as_stored_in_notebook to run it on CI